Proving that $\dim(\bar a \bar b /A) = \dim(\bar a / A \bar b) + \dim(\bar b /A)$ in a geometric structure
Let $\mathcal M$ be a geometric structure. Given $\bar a \in M^n$ and $A\subseteq M$, we define $$\dim(\bar a /A) = \min\{\text{$|\bar a'| : \bar a'\subseteq \bar a$ and $\bar a \subseteq acl(A\bar a')$ }\}$$
I'm having some trouble proving the following:
$$\dim(\bar a \bar b /A) = \dim(\bar a / A \bar b) + \dim(\bar b /A)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)$$
The more I try to prove this, the more I'm convinced it's supposed to be
$$\dim(\bar a \bar b /A) = \dim(\bar a / A \bar b) + \dim(\bar b /A \bar a)\ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \  (2)$$
but I'm having trouble finding info about this online. Is (2) the correct version of this? If not, how would you prove (1)?
If you need any clarification on the notation/definitions let me know!

No, (1) is correct. To see that (2) is wrong, let $a$ be an element which is not in $\DeclareMathOperator{\acl}{acl}\acl(\varnothing)$, and let $b = a$ (or, more generally, $b$ such that $a$ and $b$ are each algebraic over the other). Then $\dim(ab/\varnothing) = 1$, but $\dim(a/b) +\dim(b/a) = 0$.
To motivate (1), consider a space $X$ with a surjective function $\pi\colon X\to Y$. If for every $b\in Y$, the fiber $\pi^{-1}(b)$ has the same dimension $d$, then, intuitively, $\dim(X) = d + \dim(Y)$. In our case, think of $\DeclareMathOperator{\tp}{tp}\tp(\bar{c}/A)$ as defining the set of all realizations of this complete type, and $\dim(\bar{c}/A)$ as the dimension of this set. We have a projection $\pi\colon \tp(\bar{a}\bar{b}/A)\to \tp(\bar{b}/A)$, and the fiber $\pi^{-1}(\bar{b})$ is exactly $\tp(\bar{a}/A\bar{b})$. Further, for all $\bar{b}'$ realizing $\tp(\bar{b}/A)$, there is an automorphism moving $\bar{b}'$ to $\bar{b}$ over $A$, and hence moving the fiber $\pi^{-1}(\bar{b}')$ to $\pi^{-1}(\bar{b})$. So all the fibers have the same dimension, and it is reasonable to expect $\dim(\bar{a}\bar{b}/A) = \dim(\bar{a}/A\bar{b})+\dim(\bar{b}/A)$. Of course, this is only true if our notion of dimension behaves "as expected" - and in geometric theories, it does.
Ok, now for the proof.
Let $\bar{b}'$ be subtuple of $\bar{b}$ of minimal length such that $\bar{b}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{b}')$, and let $\bar{a}'$ be a subtuple of $\bar{a}$ of minimal length such that $\bar{a}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{b}\bar{a}')$.
Then $\bar{b}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{a}'\bar{b'})$, so $\bar{a}\bar{b}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{b}\bar{a'}) = \acl(A\bar{a'}\bar{b}')$. It follows that $$\dim(\bar{a}\bar{b}/A) \leq |\bar{a}'\bar{b}'| = \dim(\bar{a}/A\bar{b})+\dim(\bar{b}/A).$$
For the other inequality, let $\bar{c} = \bar{a}'\bar{b}'$ be a subtuple of $\bar{a}\bar{b}$ of minimal length such that $\bar{a}\bar{b}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{c})$, with $\bar{a}'$ a subtuple of $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}'$ a subtuple of $\bar{b}$.
Suppose $\bar{b}\not\subseteq \acl(A\bar{b}')$. Then there is some $b_i$ in $\bar{b}$ such that $b_i\notin \acl(A\bar{b}')$.
Claim: There is some $a_j$ in $\bar{a}'$ such that if $\bar{c}'$ is obtained from $\bar{c}$ by removing $a_j$ and adding $b_i$, then $|\bar{c}'| = |\bar{c}|$ and $\acl(A\bar{c}) = \acl(A\bar{c'})$.
Note that $b_i\in \acl(A\bar{a}'\bar{b}')$. Let $\bar{a}''$ be a minimal sub-tuple of $\bar{a}'$ such that $b_i\in \acl(A\bar{a}''\bar{b}')$. Since $b_i\notin \acl(A\bar{b}')$, $\bar{a}''$ is non-empty. Let $a_j$ be in $\bar{a}''$, and write $\bar{a}'''$ for $\bar{a}''$ with $a_j$ removed.
Now $b_i\in \acl(A\bar{a}'''\bar{b}'a_j)$, but by minimality, $b_i\notin \acl(A\bar{a}'''\bar{b}')$. By exchange, $a_j\in \acl(A\bar{a}'''\bar{b}'b_i)$.
Let $\bar{c}'$ be obtained from $\bar{c}$ by removing $a_j$ and adding $b_i$. Clearly $|\bar{c}'| = |\bar{c}|$. We know $b_i\in \acl(A\bar{c})$, so $\bar{c}'\subseteq \acl(A\bar{c})$. And since $\bar{a}'''\bar{b}'b_i$ is a subtuple of $\bar{c}'$, $a_j\in \acl(A\bar{c}')$, so $\bar{c}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{c}')$. Thus $\acl(A\bar{c}) = \acl(A\bar{c}')$. $\square$
Repeatedly applying the claim until $\bar{b}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{b}')$, we may assume that $\dim(\bar{b}/A)\leq |\bar{b}'|$.
Now since $\bar{a}\bar{b}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{a}'\bar{b}')$, in particular $\bar{a}\subseteq \acl(A\bar{b}\bar{a}')$, so $\dim(\bar{a}/A\bar{b})\leq |\bar{a}'|$. Putting these together, $$\dim(\bar{a}/A\bar{b})+\dim(\bar{b}/A)\leq |\bar{a}'\bar{b}'| = \dim(\bar{a}\bar{b}/A).$$

I don't get how we can use the exchange principle to build a new tuple $\bar c'$. The version of the exchange principle I know is $b \in acl(Ac)\setminus acl(A) \implies c \in acl(Ab)$, but here we have $b_i \in acl(A\bar b' \bar a')\setminus acl(A\bar b')$. Does this mean that we can find some $a_i \in \bar a'$ such that $a_i \in acl(A \bar b' b_i)$?

@EduardoMagalhães I added some more details to the application of exchange I had in mind, and I also added some motivation for why the formula (1) should not be surprising.
